# Elasticbeanstalk - apache configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a WordPress site working on Elasticbeanstalk using apache. When i run it using nginx, everything works fine, but with apache, i get the following error:

```
var/www/html/.htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here, referer: http://www.example.com/
```

Do I need to add any more configuration in elasticbeanstalk or perhaps alter the `httpd.conf` to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please check what the [tag:apache] tag has to say about server configuration questions. And [help/on-topic]